# AirPods turn my Mac laggy

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, apple-silicon, airpods

I have a Macbook M1 Pro and I'm experiencing some weird things with my AirPods (2 gen).

**The problem**

When I open my AirPods case (start the connection), the MacBook becomes laggy for approximately 30 seconds (if I want to use my keyboard it glitches what a type or the mouse moves really slowly; it's impossible to use for that 30 seconds)

After that, everything starts working normally, except when I  sometimes start or stop music, videos, or anything that produce sounds; it get laggy again for several seconds.

The exact same problem occurs when I disconnect my AirPods (removing them for my ears).

I have tried to use the AirPods with my iPhone and they seem to work ok.   I also use my MacBook with different Bluetooth products without any issue.

I would love to know if anyone has an a idea the cause and how to fix this issue

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? It makes the Mac unusable, I haven't found what is causing it.

Could you list the apps you're using, maybe we can cross-reference them and find the cause?

Comment: I don't, I have to live with this problem :/ I was able to make it less annoying disconnecting all my bluetooth devices and using only the airpods, it was the only way I found @Foxhoundn